# Multiple submit/save buttons in form

Tags: 7, forms

I wanted to add another submit/save button above a node form (for only one content type) and added the code below. The thing is that it messes up the submission, so I had to remove it.

Whats wrong with it and is ther a better way of doing this?

```
if ( $form_id == 'news_node_form' ) {
        $form['submit'] = array(
                '#type' => 'submit',
                '#value' => 'Save'
                );
        }
```

Comment: A quick grep in `node.pages.inc` shows the regular submit button there has these attributes:  `'#submit' => array('node_form_submit'),` and `'#access' => variable_get('node_preview_' . $node->type, DRUPAL_OPTIONAL) != DRUPAL_REQUIRED || (!form_get_errors() && isset($form_state['node_preview'])),` so try adding them and see. The first tells it what to call and the second checks to make sure you have access to do it.

Comment: Please be more specific: "it misses up the submission", how exactly?

Comment: It just reloads the page and therefor doesnt create the node.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you JimJamma, that worked!

Here's how my code looks now:

```
    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#access' => variable_get('node_preview_branschguiden', DRUPAL_OPTIONAL) != DRUPAL_REQUIRED || (!form_get_errors() && isset($form_state['node_preview'])),
        '#value' => t('Save'),
        '#weight' => 5,
        '#submit' => array('node_form_submit'),
    );
```